# List view activity is not working properly in switch case inside spinner class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here BookList.java is a spinner class which maintains two occurrences one is book and another author and both have their own list view class. Through switching cases inside OnItemSelected() method their intent is accessed. But the problem i'm facing is that the first list view applied intent which is for book can't be accessed but can access author intent. it would be helpful if anybody help me editing my code. Here goes the java file.

```
            public class BookList extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

                Spinner spinner;
                //private static final String[]paths = {"Book", "Author"};
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_booklist);
                    TextView t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1) ;
                    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    //ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BookList.this,
                            //android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.blist_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

                }

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

                    final Intent intent;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(BookList.this, BookListView.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            intent = new Intent(BookList.this, BookListAuthorView.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                    }



                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose a field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the item positions starts from `0` not from `1` so use this

And so 0 position will automatically trigger first time you open your activity so create a spinner array something like this for spinner

```
String arr ={"select choice","book","author"};
```

---

```
                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(BookList.this, BookListView.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(BookList.this, BookListAuthorView.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
```

plus you don't have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();'

Comment: I have already tasted this by changing case to 0 and 1 but then another problem arises it directly accesses the list view activity and i cant see my spinner activity class where i can choose the cases.

Comment: you got two options book will open `BookListView` and author will open = `BookListAuthorView` what else you expect to happen and isn't your spinner class is the current code you posted (which you can't see)

Comment: I cant see this spinner of BookList.java class and without choosing any option it takes me directly to BookListView.java class. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Beause 0 position is automatically trigger first time . Letme update the code

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion, it actually works now. :)